# What is a "Paclet"?

Tags: packages, system, paclets

I often see references to "paclets", for example the `` PacletManager` `` context, the `PacletInfo.m` file in some packages and next to downloaded computable data, `$UserBaseDirectory/Paclets`, etc.

**Question:** What are "paclets", what is their relevance to end users, and how can one use them with packages?

**Clarification:** Since I saw a `PacletInfo.m` file in several third party [packages](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/macroprocessor/macroprocessor.html) as well, I assume that they must be useful in packages and there must be some documentation on how to use them somewhere.  I am hoping someone could point me to the relevant documentation.

Comment: `PacletInfo.m` is described in the [Wolfram Workbench documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/projects/pacletinfo.html).

Comment: @WReach Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs, is this question relevant any more?

Comment: @KraZug If you are looking at distributing packages as paclets, then not really.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*Update for version 12.1*

Starting with version 12.1, paclets are now exposed as user-accessible packaging functionality.  They are documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Paclets.html).

[Todd Gayley](https://community.wolfram.com/web/tgayley) of WRI has published some preliminary documentation about [Paclets and Paclet Development](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/tgayley/Published/PacletDevelopment.nb).  There is also an associated [introductory video](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=paclet&v=2833).

---

*Original Response*

A paclet is a distribution mechanism for resources that contribute to the contents of a package.  Most of the paclet machinery is in the `PacletManager` context, which is not public API.

It appears that the only part of paclet functionality presently intended for public use involves `PacletInfo.m`, a descriptor file for Mathematica applications.  This is described in the [Wolfram Workbench documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/reference/projects/pacletinfo.html).

Comment: Do you by any chance know if this functionality can be used for automatically updating a package (in my case: a palette) from the internet?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry, I don't know about any such functionality.  However, there looks to be some interesting spelunking around `PacletInstall`, `PacletUpdate`, etc in `NotebookOpen@
 FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Autoload", 
   "PacletManager", "Kernel", "Manager.m"}`.

Comment: @WReach Are there any differences between the "official" 12.1 paclet functionality and the previous implementation?

Comment: @ChrisK I'm afraid I cannot offer a good assessment of that difference.  Some members of our community have worked hard to use the undocumented features so if the issue is of interest to you a new question may draw some interesting answers... although it is hard to "diff" against an undocumented moving target :)

Comment: @WReach Thanks for the info... I'll wait and see if it breaks anything I'm doing.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or tech note on the steps needed to develop, test, document, and publish packets?

Comment: @M.R. The most complete tutorial that I am aware of is Todd Gayley's [Paclets and Paclet Development](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/tgayley/Published/PacletDevelopment.nb) and the associated [introductory video](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=paclet&v=2833).

Answer (score 31):

Paclets are downloaded chunks of curated computable data:

> [Load-on-Demand Curated Data](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin6/content/LoadOnDemandCuratedData/)
>
> Mathematica 6 pioneers the powerful
>   concept of built-in computable data sources. An efficient
>   load-on-demand mechanism makes hundreds of gigabytes of carefully
>   curated and continually updated data immediately available inside
>   Mathematica for use in computations. Mathematica 6 introduces major
>   collections of data in mathematics, physics, chemistry, astronomy,
>   geography, linguistics and finance—all organized and aggregated for
>   the first time by Wolfram Research for direct use in computations.

From [*Mathematica* Internet Connectivity](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/InternetConnectivity.html):

> When you call a data function like FinancialData, Mathematica gets the
>   data it needs from the internet. When you click a link to a
>   documentation notebook or call a data function like CountryData,
>   Mathematica knows whether a newer version of the information is
>   available on a Wolfram Research Paclet Server, and if so it will
>   download and install the update automatically. In the case of smaller
>   paclets like documentation notebooks, this is often so fast that you
>   will not even notice it happening.

Some details of this functionality are [found here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3310):

> Mathematica‘s data functions download data paclets from our data
>   servers. Hence functions such as CityData,WeatherData, and CountryData
>   will not work on computers disconnected from the internet. It is
>   possible to transfer such paclets from an online to an offline machine
>   with the following steps:
>
> - Download your paclet of interest (e.g. CityData) to the online machine by evaluating this in Mathematica:
>
>   ```
>   CityData[All,"Preload"]
>   ```
> - Locate the paclet repository folder by evaluating:
>
>   ```
>   ToFileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Paclets", "Repository"}]
>   ```
> - And identify the subfolders starting with “CityData” in their names.
> - Copy these folders into the equivalent paclet repository folder on your offline machine. (The corresponding location on the offline
>     computer can be found using the same ToFileName evaluation from
>     above.)
> - Have the offline Mathematica installation recognize the added data paclets by evaluating :
>
>   ```
>   RebuildPacletData[]
>   ```
> - Finally, evaluate a few examples in the documentation for CityData to verify that the desired data is now available in Mathematica.

---

Specific use and format of the `PacletInfo.m` file is provided by [Scientific Arts (.nb)](http://www.scientificarts.com/worklife/notebooks/DocumentationCenterNotes.nb):

> As mentioned above, within the package directory which we are calling
>   MyApplication there will also be a file called PacletInfo.m.  This is
>   a file with a specific structure which tells Mathematica what is
>   contained within the Guides, Tutorials, and ReferencePages directories
>   and how the Documentation Center should categorize and access them. 
>   The PacletInfo.m file is a plain text file with elements that describe
>   what sorts of materials are contained in the  Guides, Tutorials, and
>   ReferencePages directories as well as things such as what Context the
>   functions described within the ReferencePages belong to.  Also it lets
>   the Documentation Center know how to list the material on the
>   Installed Add-Ons page that is linked to from the front page of the
>   Documentation Center.

Read the Notebook for much more complete coverage.

Comment: Why do some packages contain a `PacletInfo.m` file then?  See for example [this package](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/macroprocessor/macroprocessor.html).  What is the function of `PacletInfo.m` and can I make use of it in my own packages?

Comment: I clarified the question a bit.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see.  I figured you were asking this as a beginner's question.  Thanks for not completely changing the question and pulling the rug out from under me.

Comment: The downloaded computable data also has a `PacletInfo.m`, this is a relevant answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs does the linked Notebook cover what you're after?

Comment: Yes it does.  It seems it was written before this got documented (or before Workbench was released?)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Does _Mathematica_ copy the paclet in its own preferred directory? Meaning, can I delete the paclet after having installed it, or do I need to keep it in the right path?

Comment: @CHM installed it how?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `CUDAResourcesInstall["path"]`

Comment: @CHM I don't have a version that supports CUDA.  You will have to investigate this yourself.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is odd that `RebuildPacletData` is not contained in documentation. Though, `?RebuildPacletData` gives some infomation.