# Refreshing the Palettes menu

Tags: front-end, palettes, deployment

How can the contents of the Palettes menu be refreshed  (preferably programmatically) without restarting the Front End?

When droppping a new palette notebook into `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Palettes`, it will appear in the Palettes menu after restarting the Front End.  How can I make it appear there without restarting the front end?

When using the `Palettes -> Install Palette...` feature, this refresh happens automatically, so I assume it must be possible.  The source of the installation dialog notebook is available in `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources`, but I did not manage to figure out how it works yet.

Comment: I think it is already (although tangentially) answered here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2611/193

Comment: @belisarius Good find!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following command to programmatically refresh the contents of the menus in *Mathematica*:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic, Automatic}]]
```

This was mentioned by John Fultz in [this MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00288.html) as well as [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/what-is-modifying-an-init-m-that-changes-menu-palettes-order/2611#2611).