# Show StyleSheets and Palettes from custom directory in Mathematica's Menu

Tags: front-end, packages, stylesheet, palettes

I'm working on a package that needs to be installed into an arbitrary, "non standard" path (i.e., not `$BaseDirectory` or `$UserBaseDirectory`).
I have added the package's path to `$Path` in order to allow *Mathematica* to load the package via `Get` or `Needs`, and this works well.

My problem is that the package also needs to include custom stylesheets and custom palettes, and these are not available in the front-end menus (*Format-->Stylesheet* and *Palettes*, respectively) when the package is loaded from a non-standard location.

If I put the package files in `$BaseDirectory` the custom stylesheet and palette are accessible from the front-end menus, since the package follows the standard structure:

- package\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\mystyle.nb
- package\FrontEnd\Palettes\mypalette.nb

but this doesn't seem to work if it is loaded from an arbitrary path.

---

This Wolfram [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html) says that:

> Stylesheet are discovered by the front end in the following locations.

```
FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","StyleSheets"}]

FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","StyleSheets"}]
```

> Stylesheets contained in directories are grouped under submenus in the
>   Stylesheet menu. Add-on applications following the same layout also
>   add stylesheets to the menu.

---

How can I install a package in a directory that's not `$UserBaseDirectory` or `$BaseDirectory`, and still make the stylesheets and palettes available in the *Mathematica* menus?

Comment: Possibly you have to add the packages path to Option Inspector -> Global Options -> File Locations -> PalettePath.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was not aware of such option. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I added my own path inside the init.m file and when running Mathematica my palette is not listed in the menu. However, looking at the $FrontEnd option "PalettePath" I can see the right path to my palette. Now I found a similar option for StyleSheet, let me try and I'll update ehre the result.

Comment: The same, even StyleSheetPath doesn't accept my path.

Comment: I found some other hints, for Palette. The tutorial tutorial/CreatingPalettes#1453252323 says "Palettes can also be installed as part of a Wolfram System application. To add a palette to your application, create a FrontEnd\Palettes\ directory within the application folder and save the palette to this location. For example, the palette MyPalette.nb would be placed in MyApplication\FrontEnd\Palettes\." I have done the same steps but no results.

Comment: Related: [7779](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7779/how-can-i-easily-eliminate-the-dependency-of-a-stylesheet-on-a-non-built-in-styl).

Comment: Does my answer do what you need?

Answer (score 5):

The supported way to do this is to include a FrontEnd extension in the PacletInfo file, as in this example:

```
Paclet[
  Name -> "ExamplePackage", 
  Version -> "1.0.0", 
  MathematicaVersion -> "9+", 
  Description -> "An example package.", 
  Creator -> "WEG", 
  Extensions -> {
    {"Kernel", Context -> {"ExamplePackage`"}}, 
    {"Documentation", Language -> "English", LinkBase -> "ExamplePackage", MainPage -> "Guides/ExamplePackage"},
    {"FrontEnd"}
}]
```

The `{"FrontEnd"}` extension is the key part for Palettes and StyleSheets.

Add the package to the PacletManager using:

```
PacletDirectoryAdd["path"]
```

Where path is the path to the package folder or the folder that contains the package folder (and potentially other packages).

Once this is run all Palettes and StyleSheets will be added to the menus.

Comment: What do you mean by "supported"?

Comment: @Kuba - This is how Wolfram recommends to set up PacletInfo files for version 9+ (the PacletManager was rewritten for version 9) and PacletDirectoryAdd is how they recommend to add packages in non-standard locations. I worked with Harry Calkins to get this working at my organization.

Comment: I see, is there an official tutorial about how to use PacletManager?

Comment: @Kuba - No, but that would be nice. Todd Gayley helped me out with all of my questions on it. I wanted to make sure that everything that we were doing was reliable, even though it is undocumented. That meant confirming that the functionality we are using is also used internally by Mathematica in the same manner. However Harry Calkins did have a notebook showing an example package setup that was helpful. The code in my answer is based on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm busy with other stuff in these days, I'll try your suggested solution very soon.

Comment: @DavidCreech Yes, that would be nice. p.s. please consider saying more about PacletInfo.m file, how to setup it etc. Not everyone is working with WB.

Comment: @Kuba That is an expansive topic. Perhaps it should be a different question?

Comment: @DavidCreech yes, general one is probably desired, yet, there is not word about paclet info in OP so this answer may seem off topic for someone who doesn't know WB. Maybe just mentioning that this applies to projects created in WB is enough, what do you think?

Comment: @Kuba All packages, not just those created in WB, should now be using PacletInfo files. My understanding from reading the comments in the PacletManager code and talking to Todd is that Wolfram is moving towards paclets for handling everything. In fact WB isn't quite up to date - it creates package layouts using a legacy style.

Comment: @DavidCreech I'm sorry, I don't agee with your first statement. There is no official guide on that matter so that is just another undocumented feature, from a user perspective. It may be the future or packages may benefit from using that setup but people don't have time to guess what will happen or not.

Comment: @Kuba Good point that it isn't documented. But until that happens, I needed to get a large enterprise deployment working and this is what Wolfram recommended and uses for their packages. It has worked well.

Comment: @David You know a lot about this stuff, can you contribute anything interesting [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132064/12)?  I'm primarily thinking of things that are practically useful for package authors, such as the FrontEnd extension you mentioned here. But mentioning that something is strictly internal or not useful for third-party package authors is also useful.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can do that, I just cleared up my questions on the same topic with Todd Gayley last month.

Answer (score 4):

About StyleSheets, you can do:

```
AppendTo[
  CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "StyleSheetPath"], 
  "packageDir\\FrontEnd\\StyleSheets"
]
```

which will have an effect as soon as you restart MMA or evaluate

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
   FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic, Automatic}]]
```

credits to: [R.M., Refreshing the Menu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8564/5478)

---

Analogically you can add palletes to the menu:

```
AppendTo[
  CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "PalettePath"], 
  "packageDir\\FrontEnd\\Palettes"
]
```

---

Further readings:

You can learn more from: [**Front End options**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72989/5478) by Mr. Wizard