# Enabling "Update" button for installed packages

Tags: packages, documentation, development

I found that if you navigate to the "Installed Add-Ons" page in the *Wolfram Documentation Center" accessed by following

Help ▸ Wolfram Documentation ▸ [Add-ons and Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7cYo.png)

you will find a listing of all installed packages.  Then if you open up the cell for one of the packages and open the sub-cell "MANAGE", you'll find a botton titled "UPDATE", but it seems to be greyed out:

[image: Example package listing]

1. How do you enable this button (so that it's clickable) for your installed packages?
2. If you are the developer of an installed package, what needs to be done so that this button is enabled, and correctly updates the package from a given source?

Presumably `PacletInfo.m` should be appropriately modified.

Comment: E.g. for ``Shortcuts` `` package this has to be true ``PacletManager`Package`updateButtonEnabled[{
          "Shortcuts-0.0.1", 
  "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Applications\\\
Shortcuts"}]`` but I don't think this feature is ready since  ``RawBoxes@System`Dump`updateButtonGraphicsBox`` is as gray as ``RawBoxes@System`Dump`updateButtonDisabledGraphicsBox``

Comment: @Kuba Thanks!  But, feature not ready?  That button is there since at least 8.0.4.  How long could it possibly take to make it ready?

Comment: Don't ask me, have you seen any official tutorial about more than basics of `PacletManager`? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120976/5478

Comment: QuantumDot and @Kuba: Maybe the paclet needs to be downloaded from a paclet server for this to work.  See here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/968760  I won't work on this. If you figure it out, please post a self-answer.