# Loading documentation of Package installed in any directory

Tags: packages, documentation

Installing Package into `$UserBaseDirectory` or `$BaseDirectory` means automatic loading of the documentation (after calling the Package).

However, when I installed a Package into different directory (the directory is add to the `$Path`) the documentation is not loaded after calling the Package using `Needs`.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Add documentation extension to paclet.m file, should work. And the directory // PacletDirectoryAdd.

Comment: @CarlWoll yes it does.

Comment: @Kuba, can't get your idea. more explanation is needed :)

Comment: Analogously to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120976/5478 for more info search pacletinfo.m documentation project here.

Comment: @Kuba, I see. I am using Workbench but I will look at your link and work on the pacletinfo.m itself. Thanks

Comment: I used this package. In addition to help in creating documentation, there are functions for installing documentation in the system https://github.com/yurkan/userhelp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the directory containing the package directory to the paclet path.

```
PacletDirectoryAdd["/dir/to/my/pack"]
```

assuming that `PacletInfo.m` is contained within `/dir/to/my/pack/PackageName`.

This is not permanent.  It lasts only until the end of the session.

Comment: One could put this in `init.m` if permanence is wanted, no?

Comment: @J.M. That would be the thing to try, but I do not know if: (1) there's a better way (2) `PacletDirectoryAdd` is safe to use during initialization.

Comment: @J.M. I rather add this line before BeginPackage so that it is added only when it is loaded. Not the best way though.